# How do I mock client-side nextJs dynamic imports on the server side?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

This is a subtle variation to some questions that have been asked before. We're using jest to run some ssr tests:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',  // NOT jsdom
}
```

And our Next.JS components have a mixture of client-side dynamic imports, and server-side dynamic imports.

```
// server-side dynamic import
const Content = dynamic(() => import('../shared/Content'));
```

```
// client-side dynamic import
const LoginDialog = dynamic(() => import('../dialogs/LoginDialog'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

The point is, when running the ssr test, since it's running on the server-side, our snapshot should include the content from the server-side dynamic import, and should not include the content from the client-side dynamic import.

But unfortunately we're running aground because we hit one of these cases:

1. When using `testEnvironment: 'node'`, `jest-next-dynamic` complains that `preloadAll` cannot be called on the client-side dynamic imports (while it works fine on the server-side dynamic imports)
2. If we remove `jest-next-dynamic` and the call to preloadAll, then the content of the server-side dynamic import is no longer in our snapshots
3. If we go back to `testEnvironemnt: 'jsdom'`, then our ssr tests pass even if we refer to `window` or other browser-specific stuff on the server-side, which is very bad

So, the question is: how do we use jest and Next.JS to properly mock client-side dynamic imports while also continuing to implement server-side dynamic imports?

We also looked in to how to mock/spy `next/dynamic` using jest to only mock if `ssr: true` but it doesn't look like jest supports mocking depending on parameter values.